# Unpack redis set bit string in Go

Tags: go, redis, bit-manipulation, bit

Using `redis#Setbit` to set bit in a key like: `redis.Do("SETBIT", "mykey", 1, 1)`.

When I read it using `redis#Get` like `redis.Do("GET", "mykey")`, I get a bit string.

How do I unpack the string so I can get a slice of bools in Go? In Ruby, you use [String#unpack](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-unpack) like `"@".unpack` which returns `["00000010"]`

Comment: Does the following work for you: https://play.golang.org/p/64GjaXNar2 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such helper in `redigo`. Here is my implementation:

```
func hasBit(n byte, pos uint) bool {
    val := n & (1 << pos)
    return (val > 0)
}


func getBitSet(redisResponse []byte) []bool {
    bitset := make([]bool, len(redisResponse)*8)

    for i := range redisResponse {
        for j:=7; j>=0; j-- {
            bit_n := uint(i*8+(7-j))
            bitset[bit_n] = hasBit(redisResponse[i], uint(j))
        }
    }

    return bitset
}
```

Usage:

```
    response, _ := redis.Bytes(r.Do("GET", "testbit2"))

    for key, value := range getBitSet(response) {
        fmt.Printf("Bit %v = %v \n", key, value)
    }
```